# SFX Request: Russian Landscape

Tags: sfx, request

Hey guys,

So, I'm working on a short where a scene takes place in the Russian countryside during spring. and I'm having some trouble finding that. Could anyone help me out? Or recommend a site to purchase some?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're cutting an instructional film for ornithologists don't worry about the species.  This is your scene.  What kind of birds do you want to hear?  What sounds would enhance the feeling the movie cries out for?  This is where the sound editor earns his money.  Create a sound environment that dramatically does it for you and the audience will be drawn into it. If the director doesn't like he'll make you change it, but generally they turn to you and say, "Wow, very good!" If it's an African bird or Texas bird it doesn't matter.  Go for the drama.

Comment: On the one hand your right. On the other hand, if there's one thing that takes me away from a scene than it's a NY police siren in a european set movie. And, it happens a lot unfortunately. So it really ìs worthy checking your authenticity before, while and after working on a movie.

Answer (score 3):

Hi. What kind of things are you looking for? While I don't live in Russia I am in Estonia, next door, and Estonia has lot's of wide open spaces with no traffic, airplane or human sounds. If there is something specific you want maybe I can get it for you!

Answer (score 3):

Russia is pretty huge, what part of Russia are you after? I'm in finland that is also just next door but a bit further north, so if there is something specific I could help or might even have it already.
Alternatively check out this guy http://www.kaamossound.com/ he lives further north than me and has an extensive collection of local recordings.

Comment: Hi guys,

Well the scene takes place in Russia but it's unspecified where. So, I've create an ambience of light wind, wind on trees, and birds... and my problem it's with birds, which they dont belong to the scenary. If you have something that you feel it could help out I would appreciate it.  

Answer (score 2):

Hello there, i live in Russia and made some recordings of city/town ambiences which i can share. Specify please, what kind of ambience you need?

Comment: Hey Serge,
Thanks for your reasponse! I'm looking for a countryside, peacefull, during spring...if not its ok 

Comment: As the comment above says, Russia is very large and conists of many climatic zones. Nevertheless, there are some of my recordings. Maybe you'll find something useful.

http://lesser-vibes.com/town_countryside_ambiences_russia.rar

Answer (score 1):

Hi, I live in Russia and i have some countryside recordings (late spring). If you still need these sounds i'll upload'em for you.
for my field recordings I use Korg MR-1000 and Rode NT-4.

Comment: Hi Kadabba, if it's not a problem for you,yes please. Thank you very much! 